# How do I extract and convert currency values from json using Python?

Tags: python, json, loops, dictionary

this is my very first project using Python and would love a bit of help...

I'm trying to extract 3 different currency values ('EUR', 'USD' and 'GBP') from json output with goal to convert and combine these figures. I got the data from an api call to a CRM system using the requests module and have even been able to display the  individual dict values for the deals.

within the json 'data' key there are 3 values that I could use for this (example format in brackets)...
'value' (2500)
'currency' ('USD')
'formatted_value ('USD$2,500')

I thought the best way to sort these out would be to use a for loop to sort 'value' and 'currency' into the 3 lists (USD, EUR  & GBP) and from there convert each list using local rates and sum together into 1 total currency (GBP).

my code snippet for the USD bit of the for loop is below. If this had worked I would have added elif and else, but when I run this and print the us_deals list it displays []

```
us_deals = []

for value in data['data']:
    if value['currency'] is ['USD']:
        us_deals.append(value['value'])

print(us_deals)
```

I think the "if value['currency'] **is** ['USD']:" line is the problem (= instead of is didn't work). Any advice would be most welcome!

Answer (score 0):

It would be helpful if you posted the `data` structure so I can be sure, but try this. I believe you are right, it is the `"if value['currency'] is ['USD']:"` which is the problem. Unless currency is a `list` of currency types, it should be the string `'USD'` instead of the list with one string `['USD']`. And, you can compare two strings using `==`. Instead try:

```
for value in data['data']:
    if value['currency'] == 'USD':
        us_deals.append(value['value'])
```

Comment: Sam - this is so helpful and works like a charm, thank you! This is a total newbie mistake but I really appreciate your response (I was stuck on this for a long time!).